# Can't Pipe Into Grep Using unistd

Tags: linux, c

I'm trying to write a shell with IO piping, and I noticed that the program would fail specifically when piping into grep. Here's some code outlining my piping technique:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
        int pipes[2];
        pipe(pipes);
        char *argve[5];

        // "cat sh.c"
        argve[0] = "cat";
        argve[1] = "sh.c";
        argve[2] = NULL;
        if (!fork()){  
                close(pipes[0]);
                dup2(pipes[1],1);
                execvp(argve[0],argve);
                printf("ERROR\n");
        }
        close(pipes[1]);

        // "grep "include""
        argve[0] = "grep";
        argve[1] = "\"include\"";
        argve[2] = NULL;
        if (!fork()){
                dup2(pipes[0],0);
                execvp(argve[0],argve);
                printf("ERROR\n");
        }
        close(pipes[0]);

        int wstatus;
        while (wait(&wstatus)>0)
                ;
        return 0;
}
```

Executing this program produces no output when it should produce a line for every library I import in `sh.c`. This technique works for other combinations (e.g. "ls | cat" or "echo | cat"). Is there a reason why grep is refusing the pipe?

Comment: You're really looking for a nine-character string `"include"`? Fine if so, but just checking

Comment: @roaima it's just a placeholder

Comment: With the literal double-quote characters either side?

Comment: You'll want to `close(pipes[1]);` after `dup2(pipes[1],1);` and similarly `close(pipes[0]);` after `dup2(pipes[0],0);`. Otherwise you'll still have two file descriptors associated with those ends of the pipe.